# Pandas DataFrame Accessor Type Hints

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, types, pycharm

Pandas allows you to extend its DataFrame class by using the `pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor()` decorator.

While this is functional, it doesn't offer any additional type hinting capabilities.

For example, I would expect the following to type check OK and even provide type hints

```py
import pandas as pd
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor('dataset')
class Extension:
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        self._df = df
    
    def foo(self, bar) -> str:
        return "foobar";

foo = pd.DataFrame({"foo":["bar"]})
foo.dataset.foo("bar")
    ^
    No Suggestions
```

How can I get dataframe accessors to provide autocomplete?

Comment: This is not the question about Pandas per se. It's more IDE related. Auto-complete works perfectly on Jupyter.

Comment: That's because Jupyter has the benefit of actually running the code. It doesn't need type hints at all.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done somewhat hackishly using `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` and a bit of inheritance.

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
import pandas as pd
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor('dataset')
class Extension:
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        self._df = df
    
    def foo(self, bar) -> str:
        return "foobar";

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class DataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
        dataset: Extension

foo: 'DataFrame' = pd.DataFrame({"foo":["bar"]})
#    ^ you have to do this every time you transform the DataFrame
foo.dataset.foo("bar")
#           ^ autocomplete is now provided
```

Unfortunately, PyCharm does not check the `__annotations__` dictionary, or really do any dynamic type checking, so there doesn't appear to be any more universal solutions.