# How to have documentation and type hints in vs code from methods created with pandas register_dataframe_accessor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, documentation, type-hinting

I ran into some issues while trying to extend pandas dataframe API using the `register_dataframe_accessor` decorator. While I was able to create the class as indicated in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html), and use properties and methods, I noticed that in VS Code, the doctrings and type hints were not available.

In contrast, while working inside the classic jupyter notebook or jupyter-lab,both docstrings and type hints were available.

I did the same test with type-hints in a dummy method, and again it worked in Jupyter but not in VS Code Jupyter.

Is it possible to make documentation and type hints available in VS Code for additional dataframe accessor ?

```
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("geo")
class GeoAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._validate(pandas_obj)
        self._obj = pandas_obj

    @staticmethod
    def _validate(obj):
        # verify there is a column latitude and a column longitude
        if "latitude" not in obj.columns or "longitude" not in obj.columns:
            raise AttributeError("Must have 'latitude' and 'longitude'.")

    @property
    def center(self):
        # return the geographic center point of this DataFrame
        lat = self._obj.latitude
        lon = self._obj.longitude
        return (float(lon.mean()), float(lat.mean()))

    def plot(self, dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """With docstring
        plot this array's data on a map, e.g., using Cartopy
        """
        return dataframe

ds = pd.DataFrame(
    {"longitude": np.linspace(0, 10), "latitude": np.linspace(0, 20)}
)
ds.geo.plot()
```

[image: Here's the view in VS code]

[image: Here's the documentation in jupyter]

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg In that precise case I beg to differ because 1) The interesting behavior is not illustrated by the code but precisely with the images.
2) the code is the same as in the documentation provided in the link.
But I added it as a gesture of good will

Comment: You have a concrete code example (which is a good thing) to illustrate the undesired/missing behavior in your IDE. To make it possible for others to reproduce it in their similar environment, you should have the actual code in the question, not an image of it (or just a link to it). The image showing the missing info in your IDE is fine and totally serviceable because that is what the problem is about. I switched my vote now.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved in this [discuss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66501738/pandas-dataframe-accessor-type-hints).

It's need add TYPE_CHECKING:

```
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class DataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
        geo: GeoAccessor
```

you have to do this every time you transform the DataFrame.

```
ds: 'DataFrame' = pd.DataFrame()
```

After modification

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("geo")
class GeoAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._validate(pandas_obj)
        self._obj = pandas_obj

    @staticmethod
    def _validate(obj):
        # verify there is a column latitude and a column longitude
        if "latitude" not in obj.columns or "longitude" not in obj.columns:
            raise AttributeError("Must have 'latitude' and 'longitude'.")

    @property
    def center(self):
        # return the geographic center point of this DataFrame
        lat = self._obj.latitude
        lon = self._obj.longitude
        return (float(lon.mean()), float(lat.mean()))

    def plot(self, dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """_summary_

        Args:
            dataframe (pd.DataFrame): _description_

        Returns:
            pd.DataFrame: _description_
        """
        return dataframe

def main():
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        class DataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
            geo: GeoAccessor
    ds: 'DataFrame' = pd.DataFrame(
    #    ^ you have to do this every time you transform the DataFrame
    {"longitude": np.linspace(0, 10), "latitude": np.linspace(0, 20)}
    )
    ds.geo.plot()
    #           ^ autocomplete is now provided

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvAbq.png)

Comment: Hi. Sadly I already saw that post before asking my question. The trouble is that it result in creating a new class for dataframe not enhancing the one from pandas, the author itself describe it as quirky in the post you linked.